# Tensorflow Functional API -> Concat Op: Can't concatenate scalars (use tf.stack instead) [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

```
class AutoEncoder(tf.keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim):
        super(AutoEncoder, self).__init__()
        
        self.latent_dim = latentDim
        self.latent = tf.random.uniform(shape=[latent_dim,])
        
        encoder_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
        encoder_concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([self.latent, encoder_input])
        encoder_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(encoder_concat)
        encoder_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(encoder_dense)
        encoder_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.latent_dim)(encoder_dense)
        self.latent_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=encoder_input, outputs=encoder_output)
        decoder_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))
        decoder_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(decoder_input)
        decoder_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(decoder_dense)
        decoder_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(decoder_dense)
        decoderOutput = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128)(decoder_dense)
        self.decoder_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=decoder_input, outputs=decoder_output)
        
    def call(self, tokens):
        for i in range(len(tokens)):
            self.latent = self.latent_model(tokens[i])
        decoded = self.decoder_model(self.latent)
        return decoded
autoencoder = AutoEncoder(128)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=losses.MeanSquaredError())
```

My model takes two inputs which the model concatenates together. Unfortunately, when I attempt to run the model, I receive an error which recommends me to use tf.stack rather than Concatenate. The issue with this is that I am using the Functional API and tf.stack is not a layer. Is there a way to correct this?

I have tried using the following code:

```
input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(128,))
input2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
concat_input = tf.stack([input1, input2])
```

However, this doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: It will be easier to spot the problem if you can put a reproducible example with dummy data, right now even there is no traceback. 1st `concat_input` will run fine if we run the code above.